# Groupby and Standardise values in Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I have a Pyspark dataframe of the type

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| B | 10 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 6 |

and I'd like to perform an operation able to generate something a DataFrame having the standardised value **with respect to its group**.

In short, I should have:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1.26012384 |
| B | 1.4083737 |
| A | -1.18599891 |
| B | -0.81537425 |
| B | -0.59299945 |
| A | -0.07412493 |

<strike>I *think* this should be performed by using a groupBy and then some agg operation but honestly I'm not really sure on how to do it</strike>.

Comment: What is your desired output, and why?  In other words what do you mean by standardised value.

Comment: @Andrew Should be clearer now

Comment: But what logic are you using?  How are you coming up with those values?  How does the first row result in 1.26012384?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the mean and stddev in each group using Window functions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Value', 
    (F.col('Value') - F.mean('Value').over(Window.partitionBy('Group'))) / 
    F.stddev_pop('Value').over(Window.partitionBy('Group'))
)

df2.show()
+-----+--------------------+
|Group|               Value|
+-----+--------------------+
|    B|  1.4083737016560922|
|    B| -0.8153742483272112|
|    B| -0.5929994533288808|
|    A|  1.2601238383238722|
|    A| -1.1859989066577619|
|    A|-0.07412493166611006|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Note that the order of the results will be randomized because Spark dataframes do not have indices.